# checking an image for size in php?

Tags: php, image

i want to check an images size thats already uploaded to the server:
psuedocode

```
if (checksize($image) >10mb {

die

}
```

can i do something like that in php? thanks :)_)

Comment: google -> php file size -> i feel lucky-> http://php.net/filesize Not a rocket science, eh?

Comment: if its not rockets science, why dnt you answer it!!! thats the whole point of stackoverflow!!!

Comment: I think the Col. is trying to teach you to fish, instead of just giving you a fish.

Comment: sorry :(( im a bit rude sometimes, its right what your saying!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `$image` is a path to a file somewhere on the filesystem:

```
if(filesize($image) > (10 * 1024 * 1024)){  // is it larger than 10mb?
   die('too big');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the PHP documentation.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php